# Java Generics: Special usage <T extends Object & Interface>

Tags: java, generics

I often find code which uses generics in Java like this:

```
public static <T extends Object & Interface> foo(T object) {
    ...
}
```

Since in Java every class inherites from object class I'm not sure if `extends Object` gives a special meaning or is used for special purposes. Can anyone tell me if there is a different background using this or this is implicit given when you take `<T extends Interface>`?

Comment: I'm curious, where do you "often" find this code?

Comment: Please provide an *exact* signature of the method, not artificial example. Your `foo` lacks the return type and will not compile. Also I have strong feeling that the argument was not just `T`, but something like `List<T>`. It would also be nice if you point where you saw such method. I think I can answer why it's necessary, but I need the exact details.

Comment: @TagirValeev You are not right. It was only T. I found this example in the book "Der Weg zum Java-Profi" by Michael Inden. Of course there is a return statement in the original code. My question was only concerning the <T extends Object & Interface> tag. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tunaki See my last comment. But I saw it more often in some codes from projects of my student colleagues and wondered if this is redundant or not.

Comment: @JulianL., ok, I don't know what was the reason in your book, but I posted the case when it can be reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<T extends Object & Interface>
```

That `Object` is clearly redundant and typically equals to

```
<T extends Interface>
```

Note that using `Interface` as a class name is highly discouraged.

Comment: Why is it highly discouraged? Just curios. SomeClass.Interface is used in our projects and it works just fine.

Comment: @momo There is already a key word called `interface` is there, so people may confuse and A real class never be an `Interface` :). Coming to your code, `SomeClass.Interface`, what is `Interface` there ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was not code from my projects, the interface name was only one example.

Comment: @JulianL. If that is the case, there is no need of that last note in my answer :) Happy coding.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ The Interface represents teh interface of SomeClass. For instance, Vehicle.Interface would represent the Interface of vehicle. Ratehr than naming it VehicleInterface and place it in the same package, I find it neater to just place it inside Vechile and calling it Interface.

Answer (score 5):

This *may* be necessary to make your code backwards-compatible on *binary* level. Suppose that you have the following utility class:

```
public class Utils {
    public static <T> int length(T obj) {
        if(obj instanceof CharSequence) {
            return ((CharSequence)obj).length();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It's published as a library and used in some applications like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Utils.length("foo"));
    }
}
```

Works fine. However later you decided that it's good to limit your method only to implementations of some interface `CharSequence` as for other objects it always returns 0 anyways and seems that nobody uses your method with non-CharSequence parameter. So you change the signature to

```
public static <T extends CharSequence> int length(T obj) { ... }
```

Now if you link the `Main` class with new version of your library, it will fail with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. That's because the *erased* signature of your method changed. Before it was `int length(Object obj)`, but now it's `int length(CharSequence obj)`. If you recompile the `Main` class, it will work fine, but it's not always possible to recompile all the existing code. Thus the trick could be performed:

```
public static <T extends Object & CharSequence> int length(T obj) { ... }
```

Now you're actually limiting the parameter to `CharSequence` interface, but the erased signature is back to `int length(Object obj)` (the erased type is always the first in the chain of `A & B & C & ...`, it's officially documented), so the new version of `Utils` class is binary compatible with the old code.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, any `T` would implicitly extend `Object` anyway. Explicitly defining `T extends Object` is completely redundant, and you could (and probably should) remove it, and just define `T extends Interface`.