# Explanation of a Generic code snippet from oracle JAVA Docs

Tags: java, generics

The below code snippet is from oracle docs:
I have a few doubts about the syntax. Need proper and detailed explanation.

*Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range [begin, end) of a list.*

```
public final class Algorithm {
    public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

        T maxElem = list.get(begin);

        for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
            if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
                maxElem = list.get(begin);
        return maxElem;
    }
}
```

1. Why does the method type parameter `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>`
   `T` has to extend both `Object` and `Comparable`. What will be the issue or difference if it were just
   `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`?
2. Why does the type parameter for `Comparable<? super T>` cannot be just `Comparable<T>`?
3. What would be the difference if the type parameter for List were just `List<T>` instead of `List<? extends T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the most part, `Object` is redundant here. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795995/java-generics-special-usage-t-extends-object-interface) for more info.
2. If you constrain it to only `T extends Comparable<T>`, that means if I have a `Dog` that can be compared to any `Animal` (`Dog implements Comparable<Animal>`), and I want the method to give me the "maximum" `Dog` in a list of `Dog`s (I should be able to do this), the method will return an `Animal` instead. `T` can't be `Dog`, since `Dog` does not implement `Comparable<Dog>`.

   Saying `Comparable<? super T>` allows `T`s that implement `Comparable<SomeSuperclassOfT>` to be used.
3. This is similar to 2. If you make it `List<T>`, then I can't give you a `List<Dog>` and ask you to return an `Animal` (`T` can't be `Animal` if I pass a `List<Dog>`). However, as far as I can tell, this doesn't really affect much in practice, because I can still convert the returned `Dog` to an `Animal` if I want.